Как ограничить область поиска объекта с помощью bbox?
Пробую ограничить область поиска с помощью bbox , добавляя в запрос соответстующий параметр (соответствует Республике Карелия):

url ="https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=...4f133c26d&format=json&bbox=29.306117,60.679619~37.946517,66.668643&geocode="+_searchString;

Однако результаты содержат объекты из других районов мира. Что не так?

Увидел. Нужно добавить параметр

& rspn=1

